# Incoming number during a call in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, call, telephony, phone-state-listener

I am running following code, its compiling but I am not getting any result or toast displayed please help...

CustomBroadcastReceiver.java
this class will receive the action phone state change and will instantiate the customephonestatelistener

```
public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

TelephonyManager telephony = 
(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener(context);

telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
String phoneNr= bundle.getString("incoming_number");
    Log.v(TAG, "phoneNr: "+phoneNr);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "phoneNr: "+phoneNr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}
}
```

CustomPhonestateListener.java

This class is main operating class

```
public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

private static final String TAG = "CustomPhoneStateListener";

private Context mContext;

public CustomPhoneStateListener(Context context) {


// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
mContext = context;
}

public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){

    Log.v(TAG, "WE ARE INSIDE!!!!!!!!!!!");

     Log.v(TAG, incomingNumber);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, "WE ARE INSIDE!!!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();

    switch(state){
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    Log.d(TAG, "RINGING");
                    break;
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />

            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: please upload the logcat of your code

Comment: Please edit to correct code for CustomBroadcastReceiver, what's shown here is not valid java

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***"But now the problem is I have to reboot the device in order to start this service..any suggestion where I am being wrong now??"***

The reason that you have to restart your phone is that in your AndroidManifest.xml file you have allowed for only one action...

```
<!-- Your Problem is here -->
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

You have set your BroadcastReceiver to only start when the phone is BOOTED.
To fix this, you need to use the answer provided by DR VOLT.

Just add the actions PHONE_STATE and NEW_OUTGOING_CALL to your receivers 
For Example:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />           
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This will then start your broadcast receiver whenever these actions occur.

Answer (score 1):

Thnx for the answers...I tried another approach and following code seems to work..Joined both receiver and phonestatelistener..**But now the problem is I have to reboot the device in order to start this service**..any suggestion where I am being wrong now??

```
public class IncomingCallReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context mContext;
private Intent mIntent;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;
    mIntent = intent;
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int events = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE;
    tm.listen(phoneStateListener, events);
}

private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        String callState = "UNKNOWN";
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            callState = "IDLE";
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            // -- check international call or not.
            if (incomingNumber.startsWith("00")) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"International Call- " + incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                callState = "International - Ringing (" + incomingNumber+ ")";
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Local Call - " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                callState = "Local - Ringing (" + incomingNumber + ")";
            }
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            String dialingNumber = mIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            if (dialingNumber.startsWith("00")) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"International - " + dialingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                callState = "International - Dialing (" + dialingNumber+ ")";
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Local Call - " + dialingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                callState = "Local - Dialing (" + dialingNumber + ")";
            }
            break;
        }
        Log.i(">>>Broadcast", "onCallStateChanged " + callState);
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
};

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your manifest file, you must have this:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />                
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

instead of :

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />                
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```