# How to check given phone number is international or non-international number in android?

Tags: android, sms, phone-number

My requirement is to find out the message recipient number is an International number or National number.

Is there any android API or any third party library available to implement the same.

I want to use libphonenumber google API[android/externals/libphonenumber] but don't know how to check International and Non-international number.

Comment: please refer this [reference link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659536/incoming-number-during-a-call-in-android


I hope its useful to you..

Comment: refer this link

[reference link 1][1]


[reference link 2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132724/checking-if-call-being-made-is-international
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659536/incoming-number-during-a-call-in-android


I hope its useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso() would help you determine 'to which country the call is being made' as it will return your country's ISO.

Moreover, length of ISD codes vary across countries. For some countries it is 1, for some it's 2, for some it's 3 and for others it's 4. So you will need to extract/make 4 different keys of these lengths from the outgoing number as I have shown below:

Say the out going number is +91-XXX-XXX-XXXX. then you'll create 4 keys as:

9 (1 digit key)
91 (2 digit key)
91X (3 digit key)
91XX (4 digit key)
Now check if any of these 4 keys is present in this list: ISO List .

[EDIT: Alternative Solution]

Again, if you only need to determine if the call being made is international or not then you can simply check for below condition:

```
if(outgoing-number `startswith` "00" || outgoing-number does not `startswith` your "country's-    ISD-code") {
    //it's an international call;
} else {
    //it's a domestic call;
}
```

Comment: Hey this is same answer in this stackoverflow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132724/checking-if-call-being-made-is-international.

Comment: that's why i was posting

Comment: Better in this case give link of that answer, so who has given original answer he gets its credit.

Comment: sorry for that next time i will be careful

Comment: @VijayBarbhaya The algorithm you specified is incorrect: first of all, if the number dialed starts with the `+` character, then by definition it is an international call (or an invalid number) as "`+`" is the universal prefix for E164 dialing. Second "`00`" is only an international dialing code in some countries. Third, checking the current ISD and comparing it to the number dialed assumes the DNID is a full E164 number - which may not be correct. Many countries allow dialing a zone-local number by starting it with "`0`", while others have such a complex setup that a simple algo isn't useful.

Comment: For example, what does it mean if a russian phone is dialed 8532145678 ? Are they calling Macau or the next city over? How about 74992345678 ? Hint: both numbers are local dialing.

Answer (score 2):

Rather use the google library which is used internally in Android as well.

http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/